# Растянуть imageView по высоте относительно ширины

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, picasso

Имеется `Listview`, в котором есть `ImageView`(картинки загружаются с помощью пикассо с сервера):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/list_view_background"
            android:padding="5dip" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription=""
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        >
</ImageView>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_400"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtViewName">
</TextView>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewStatus"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</TextView>
```

```
Picasso
                        .with(view.getContext())
                        .load("http://api.xxx.ru/v1/stream/poster/3/".concat(cameraSmallDTOList.get(position).getKey()))
                        .fit()
                        .error(R.drawable.offline_image)
                        .into(thumbnail);
```

**Вопрос:**
Как сделать ширину на весь экран, а высоту пропорционально ширине?

Comment: Попробуйте `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY" ;
```

или

```
android:scaleX="";
 android:scaleX=";
```

"

Comment: fitXY уже написан и сейчас картинка совсем не отображается

Comment: попробуй задать точную высоту

Comment: допустим 200 дип

Comment: и проверь так )

Comment: получилось , ,,,,,,,,,????

Comment: если задать высоту, то конечно получится, но тогда если я поверну экран картинка будет выглядеть как сосиска, а мне надо растягивать высоту так, чтобы картинка и на планшете и в горизонтальном режиме смотрелась хоть и большой, но пропорциональной, благо разрешение картинок хорошее

Comment: запоми никогда не делай так одну фотку на се разрешения)создай другой хмл для поворота и все*

Comment: и когда телефон сменит ориентацию то бует читаться хмл для другой ориентации

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, решение было любезно предоставлено в чате андроид разработки в телеграмме.

```
public class AspectRatioImageView extends ImageView {
private static final String TAG ="AspectRatioImageView";
private static final float DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO = 1.5f;
private final float mAspectRatio;
public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AspectRatioImageView);
    mAspectRatio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.AspectRatioImageView_aspect_ratio, DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO);
    a.recycle();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int newWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int newHeight = (int) (newWidth / mAspectRatio);

    setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, newHeight);
 }
}
```

в ресурсах:

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="AspectRatioImageView">
    <attr name="aspect_ratio" format="float" />
</declare-styleable>
```

разметка:

```
<AspectRatioImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:aspect_ratio="1.77"
        >
</AspectRatioImageView>
```